# Showing date/time in netstat

Tags: linux, netstat

Is it possible to have netstat show the date/time the connection was established?  Is this information even stored anywhere in Linux?

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/296853/determining-at-what-time-a-currently-open-tcp-connection-was-created

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with [ipclog & constat](http://www.mm.kay-mueller.de/constat.html)

Answer (score 6):

The `-p` option of `netstat` allows to get the *process ID* of the process that initiated the connection.
Used in conjunction with the `-a` (all) and `-n` (numeric) options

```
  netstat -anp
```

The list of sockets is displayed along with useful information

```
  unix 3  [ ]  STREAM   CONNECTED  60670  7392/firefox-bin
```

Using `ps -ef` (or `psgrep`) get the information associated to the 7392 process, like `STIME`

```
  ps -ef | grep 7392

  UID  PID  PPID  C STIME TTY      TIME CMD
  me  7392  7388  2 09:37 ?    00:01:34 /usr/lib/firefox-3.6.10/firefox-bin
```

The process was started at 09:37.

Comment: This only state that the process has started at a certain time it does not provide any information about a specific connection time. Firefox that you give in example, he will establish a lot of connection for the many pages that you open the time of firefox runing has no related information of what time took a connection.

Comment: @Gopoi Of course, this is just an example. I assume the author knows the difference between a process and a connection. This will be relevant if the process starts the connection at first, and dies with it.

Answer (score 5):

I have never seen any network structures for holding time a connection was established.  The information can be logged by stateful firewalls.  However, they only track when the last activity occurred.

In some cases, it is roughly derivable from when the process servicing the connection was created.

Answer (score 3):

No I checked at the man page of netstat and there is no way of knowing the time of an established connection using netstat.

And I don't think it is stored anywhere because connection are so dynamic.